# The white bellbird (Procnias albus)

Tags: translation, learning, meaning-in-context

So, there's that bird. The **white bellbird** (*Procnias albus*). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_bellbird And I need its name in **Esperanto**. Naturally, I've tried the automatic translators, but **Google**, for example, translates it a "**blanka sonorilbirdo**" and I'm pretty sure it just translates the words as is. Without treating them as a proper name. Can anyone help me with this? How do we call this exact bird? Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Brazil, the genus Procnias is known by its indigenous name 'araponga', so the author of the Esperanto Wikipedia article named it 'arapongo' (1), apparently following the Portuguese Wikipedia page.

def.fontoj.net (2) (biological terminology in German, Latin and Esperanto) notes 'arapongo' but prefers 'proknio', so Procnias albus is 'blanka proknio'. Since we usually follow the Latin when naming plants and animals, it seems 'proknio' is the way to go.

(1) https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arapongo
(2) http://def.fontoj.net/Voegel.html  (enter procnias next to Suchbegriff and click Finden)